# Mutating two dimensional list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I'm Trying to make a more advanced Tic Tac Toe program with an 'infinite' amount of lines/rows.
But when I try to mutate the list, it changes the whole column instead of just one spot.

```
size = 4
board = size * [size*[' ']]
board[0][1] = 'x'
#output:
#[[' ', 'x', ' ', ' '],
# [' ', 'x', ' ', ' '],
# [' ', 'x', ' ', ' '],
# [' ', 'x', ' ', ' ']]
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

It occurs because the inner list each row is made of is the same object that gets repeated.

You can change it to

```
board = [
    [' ']*size
    for _ in range(size)
]
```

Or use a double list comprehension

```
size = 4
board = [
    [' ' for _ in range(size)]
    for _ in range(size)
]
board[0][1] = 'x'
print(board)
```

which both produce

```
[[' ', 'x', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response!

Comment: You're welcome.  If it helps/solves your question please upvote/accept my answer

Comment: I'd like to, but my score is too low to upvote your answer. :(

Answer (score 2):

Kudos to @Pynchia for beating me to the answer. Here is my version of code. I think the problem you were having was a result of your method of creating a list of lists.

```py
size = 4

# simple way to create a list of lists
board = [size * [' '] for i in range(4)]

board[0][1] = 'x'
print(board)
```

Output will be as expected.

Comment: :D and typing on a mobile phone is pretty bad. Upvoted

Comment: Much appreciated!